# Using T4MVC JavaScriptReplaceableUrl

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm trying to use T4MVC to make action links strongly typed and easier to maintain.

Example from [HERE](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation)

```
var myUrl=<%= Url.JavaScriptReplacableUrl(MVC.Dinners.Display())%>
//myUrl will be Dinners/Display/{dinnerId} 
var myFinalUrl=myUrl.replace("{dinnerId}", dinnerId);   //this will have whatever route shape you defined in routing table!
```

I've seen multiple examples of how to use JavaScriptReplaceableUrl, but when I try to use it I get a compile time error that I'm not specifying the actions parameters.

What am I missing here?!

```
var theURL = @Url.JavaScriptReplaceableUrl(MVC.SIXBNY.GetDashboardData());
```

I've modified my route config, not sure if thats whats wrong or not.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "GetDashboardData",
                "SIXBNY/GetDashboardData/{fromDateTime}/{toDateTime}/{pvResultsBatchID}/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}",
                new { fromDateTime = UrlParameter.Optional, toDateTime = UrlParameter.Optional, pvResultsBatchID = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional, pageSize = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: What's the specific compile error? And are you sure that it's at all related to `JavaScriptReplacableUrl`, and is not instead strictly related to the `MVC.SIXBNY.GetDashboardData()` call?

Comment: David!  Exactly the person I was hoping for, lol. Error is "No overload for method 'GetDashboardData' takes 0 arguments"  So ya, its the MVC.SIXBNY.GetDashboardData call.  Wondering how to get rid of this as  examples show the call being made this way without the parameters so that you can replace the parameters afterwards with the javascript var values.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, T4MVC generates parameterless constructors in the derived class, e.g. like [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/T4MVCSampleApp/blob/139fd5d6db587c9af7214b8b46d1808e91646f62/T4MVCSampleApp/HomeController.generated.cs#L122-L139). This is what allows that kind of code to compile.

Can you look at your generated code to see if it looks much different from that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will try to get back to you by end of day.

Comment: Seems like @Hardycore didn't manage to get back to you at the end of the day